# How can I automate sending push notification when an event occurs in back-end of android app provided I'm using Firebase as Backend

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

Consider a whatsapp group. When any user texts in group, all the participants receive a notification.
Consider Youtube, whenever a content creator uploads a video, I get notifications.
These are all automated.
How to do this? I use Firebase as backend in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

You need back-end services that you communicate with through an Api from your app. Think of this as a communication layer between Firebase and your app.

Generally this can be considered as a REST API. Here is more reading:
https://restfulapi.net/rest-api-design-tutorial-with-example/